# Narrow down search from search results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am in a situation where I have to create a query dynamically that norrows down my search results. I need to add "AND" condition in the query dynamically depending upon user selection from subject/standard checkbox.

> ```
> SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, City, Subject_1, Subject_2, Subject_3, 
>        Standard_From, Standard_To FROM TutorProfile WHERE City = 'Mumbai'  AND (Subject_1 = 'Maths' OR Subject_2 = 'Maths' OR Subject_3
>  = 'Maths') AND (Subject_1 = 'Physics' OR Subject_2 = 'Physics' OR Subject_3 = 'Physics') .. AND (Standar_From = 'Class XII') ..
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SubjectCommand VARCHAR(50)

SET @SubjectCommand = ''

IF (SubjectIsSelected)
BEGIN
    SET  @SubjectCommand = 'AND (Subject_1 = ''Maths'' OR Subject_2 = ''Maths'' OR Subject_3 = ''Maths'')'
END

SET @SQL = 'SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, City, Subject_1, Subject_2, Subject_3, 
   Standard_From, Standard_To FROM TutorProfile WHERE City = ''Mumbai''' +@SubjectCommand 

EXEC(@SQL)
```